# How to query a Ruby on Rails object's nested attribute?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a User model and a Product model. The User has one product and the Product has one user. To create the User and Product models, I have a single form that creates both using nested attributes.

I am trying to create a search that can look for a User based on their name, email address or Product serial number. I have this working when looking up a User's name or email address, but I don't know how to go about looking up a User's Product by serial number in the same form.

So I'm trying to search User.last_name, User.email AND User.product.serial - cannot figure out how to go about this.

**Here is my User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :allow_destroy => true

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

  def self.search(query)
    where("last_name = ? OR email = ?", query, query)
  end
end
```

**And my Product model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

  validates :serial, presence: true
end
```

**My User view that contains the search field**

```
<%= form_tag(users_path, method: "get", :id => "user_search_form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search users" %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search", :name => nil ) %>
<% end %>
```

**The relevant part of my Users controller**

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
  else
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
    @product = @users.product 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def self.search(query)
  joins(:products)
    .where("last_name = :query OR email = :query OR products.serial = :query", 
      query: query)
end
```

Comment: works! thanks! is the period before "where" there because you're chaining the query?

Comment: Yes it is. I just split up the line there because it was quite long.